# How to update specific value in my csv file using python

Tags: python, database, csv, raspberry-pi2

I have some problem while doing my project. Currently i would like to update my csv file details. In my csv file there is matric id row, type row, weight row, points row, time row.

my problem is, if the same user use my program, the details of the user will not total up. in this case i would like to total up my points. so if the same user use my project the user will know there total points. do i need to create another function to call my points value in csv file, so the system will then calculate the total points then display it in another new row which is total points row. Please helps me. thanks.

This is my coding. i am using Python in Raspberry Pi.

print "Tared..."

```
        raw_input("put something on:")

        name, small, large = open_hid()
        print small

        nsmall = small / 11000.0 * 100
        ntotal = nsmall * 50 #kertas/aluminum/plastik (bonus point)
        #merit = ntotal * 0.01
        print "Your persentage is:"
        print ("%.2f" % nsmall)
        print "Your bonus point is:"
        print ("%.2f" % ntotal)
        with open('sensor2.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
            # Write a header row with the name of each column.
            writer.writerow(['MatricID', 'Recycle Type', 'Weight', 'Persentage', 'Bonus Points', 'Time'])
            # Now loop generating new fake sensor readings every second and writing them
            # to the CSV file.
            while True:
                # Make some fake sensor data.
                reading_time = datetime.datetime.now()
                matricID = ID
                recycleType = option
                weight = small
                persentage = ("%.2f" % nsmall)
                bonusPoint = ("%.2f" % ntotal) 

                # Print out the data and write to the CSV file.
                print('MetricID: {0} Recycle Type: {1} Weight: {2} Persentage: {3} Bonus Points: {4} Time: {5}'.format(matricID, recycleType, weight, persentage, bonusPoint,reading_time))
                writer.writerow([matricID, recycleType, weight, persentage, bonusPoint,reading_time])
                break
            csv_file.close()
    elif option == '2':
```

Comment: Can anyone help me. Sob3

Comment: You posted too much code. Slim down your post with only the relevant parts and you'll see that more people will help.

Comment: It's not good idea. file is a stream, streams are not editable. so you have to read a chink from file, edit and write it to a new file.